# How to get filter coefficients of ButterWorth filter in C++

Tags: c++, filter, lowpass-filter

I am looking the code of Butter worth low pass filter in C++ to with second order in order to get filter coefficients of Butter Worth filter. A pseudocode would be helpful as well. And the number of filter coefficients A and B of Butter worth filter is equal, aren't they?

Comment: The number of filter coefficients is indeed the same. Any reason why you chose a Butterworth filter for a digital implementation?

Comment: I want to smooth data, eliminate high frequency, obtain low frequency.

Comment: Any low-pass filter does that. Why **Butterworth** ?

Comment: I know it. Cause I am working on video stabilization and many researchers used other filter such as average, Kalman, Gaussain..... I want to try Butter worth filter to find idea.